# "the same as" or "the same thing as"

Tags: word-usage, syntactic-analysis, sentence-patterns

When comparing words, do you say

> "X means the same as Y"

or

> "X means the same *thing* as Y"

I understand you could get around this and be more clear by saying :

> "X has the same meaning as Y"

or any other clearer formulation, but I am genuinely curious about choosing between the two phrases above.

Answer (score 1):

'The same' has a determiner and an adjective, so it is leading to a noun.  'As' is not a noun, so the noun must have been elided.  The most basic noun is 'thing', so that is what can be implied and inferred.  PS: this 'as Y' is also a shortcut, for 'that Y [repeat verb]':  'X means the same [thing] that Y means.'

Answer (score -1):

Same can be either an adjective or a pronoun. They are both correct.

After all these years you look exactly the same. (pronoun)
I am talking about the same thing. (adjective)

Comment: No, that's not right. When you say *the same*, that is not a noun. You can't have **two sames*.

Comment: @tchrist Looks like it might be a typo, since "pronoun" is mentioned the line before. Violet Bear, you should [edit] your question.

Comment: Thank you. I've just edited it. Yes, it's a pronoun

Answer (score -2):

They are both equally correct.

Comment: Please provide some basis for the conclusion you offer here; without further argument or explanation, the conclusion is not especially helpful to  reader who wants to understand your thinking.